# Atascado en una función

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

> Ejercicio 1 Crear un función llamada devolver distintos que reciba 3 integers como
> parámetros. Si la suma de los 3 números es mayor a 15, va a devolver el numero mayor.
> Si la suma de los 3 números es menor a 10, va a devolver el numero menor.
> Si la suma de los 3 números es un valor entre 10 y 15 (incluidos) va a devolver el numero
> de valor intermedio

He progresado con él, sin embargo no me devuelve lo que necesito, este es mi código:

```py
def devolver_distintos(num1,num2,num3):
    
    suma = int(num1) + int(num2) + int(num3)
    numeros = []

    for n in range(3):
        n = num1,num2,num3
        numeros.append(n)

    if suma > 15:
        print(max(numeros))
    elif suma < 10:
        print(min(numeros))
    elif suma == range(10,15):
        print(numeros(range(10,15)))

    return numeros

print(devolver_distintos(1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando intentas poner los números en tu lista estas agregando 3 veces una tupla de números

```
for n in range(3):
    n = num1,num2,num3
    numeros.append(n)
```

Esto genera lo siguiente:

```
[(num1,num2,num3), (num1,num2,num3), (num1,num2,num3)]
```

En lugar de hacerlo con un `for` podrías poner directamente los números en una lista

```
numeros = [int(num1), int(num2), int(num3)]
```

Y calcular la suma de la siguiente forma:

```
suma = sum(numeros)
```

La parte de obtener el máximo y mínimo es correcta dentro de lo que cabe, pero en lugar de utilizar `print` puedes utilizar `return` para que tu función no imprima el resultado, lo devuelva. Por ejemplo:

```
return max(numeros)
```

Y para calcular el número de valor intermedio (El que no es ni máximo ni mínimo) podrías ordenar la lista y obtener el valor de en medio. Al tener una lista de 3 elementos, si la lista está ordenada, el valor de `numeros[1]` correspondería al número que no es máximo ni mínimo

Ejemplo completo:

```
def devolver_distintos(num1,num2,num3):
    
    numeros = sorted([int(num1), int(num2), int(num3)])
    suma = sum(numeros)

    if suma > 15:
        return max(numeros)
    elif suma < 10:
        return min(numeros)
    else:
        return numeros[1]

print(devolver_distintos(1,12,2))
```

Ten en cuenta que la función no pide ni evalúa que los números sean diferentes

Comment: Gracias amigo, tengo que respetar mejor las diferencias entre las tuplas, diccionarios y listas ( () {} [] ). Nunca llegue a pensar en el método sorted en parte por que lo desconocía, había probado con el .sort pero ese lo ordena en el sitio, bueno  MIL GRACIAS POR AYUDARME A COMPRENDER....

Comment: @LeoLopez , si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como respuesta correcta, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares, al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas